# How to get specific data from an alternative db in a Laravel 5.7 app with multiple DBs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I got a `Laravel 5.7` app that uses 2 DB, apart from the original one with users.

For testing, I'm trying to get data from one of the alternatives, called `postal_codes`.

My controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $propiedades = DB::connection('postalcodes')
        ->select('SELECT * FROM postal_code')
        ->get();

        // Saca todos los posts de la bd
        // $posts = Post::all();

        return view('admin.posts.index', compact('propiedades'));
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('admin.posts.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){


        // return $request->all();
        $post = new Post;
```

Though, I get an error on:

```
    $propiedades = DB::connection('postalcodes')
    ->select('SELECT * FROM postal_code')
    ->get();
```

Specifically in the `->get()` part.

The error says: `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function get() on array`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
$propiedades = DB::connection('postalcodes')
    ->table('postal_code')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Good. This works. Question and I may give you green check: is that the only way to do it?

Comment: Thanks. You can check how to do other way in laravel Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

But it is easiest way.

Comment: Also, how could I get more data?

Comment: more data? Please explain